# How to align drop down menu from vertical line to horizontal line?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

- I am trying to align my drop down menu in an horizontal line but right now its in vertical line.
- so I took the flexbox example from w3 schools and made the changes.
- in the demo code its working fine where you can see 1,2,3,4 in horizontal line.
- where as if I include those classes inside my slect tag its breaking.
  **- I debugged and found they have given flexgrow to the root class.**
- even I remove its not working.
- can you tell me how to fix it so that in future I will fix it myself.
- providing my rlevant code snippet and snadbox below below.
- all my code is in AutoCompleteComponent.js

https://codesandbox.io/s/4x9lw9qrmx

```
queryBuilderContainer: {
    display: "flex",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    backgroundColor: "DodgerBlue ",
    border: "1px solid red "
    // width: 100,

    // display: flex;
    // flex-wrap: wrap;
    // background-color: DodgerBlue;
  },
  queryBuilderContainerItem: {
    border: "1px solid black ",
    backgroundColor: "red ",
    width: 100,
    margin: 10,
    textAlign: "center",
    //lineHeight: 75,
    fontSize: 30
  },
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    height: 250
  },
  input: {
    display: "flex",
    padding: 0
  },
  valueContainer: {
    display: "flex",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    overflow: "hidden"
  },

nossr0901
```

```or-tag-here
  <NoSsr className={classes.queryBuilderContainer}>
            <Select
              className={classes.queryBuilderContainerItem}
              classes={classes}
              styles={selectStyles}
              options={this.state.suggestions}
              components={components}
              value={this.state.single}
              onChange={this.handleChange("network")}
              placeholder="Search a to do"
            />
            <Select
              className={classes.queryBuilderContainerItem}
              classes={classes}
              styles={selectStyles}
              options={this.state.nameSuggestions}
              components={components}
              value={this.state.names}
              onChange={this.handleChange("location")}
              placeholder="Search name"
            />
            <div className={classes.divider} />
            <Select
              className={classes.queryBuilderContainerItem}
              classes={classes}
              styles={selectStyles}
              options={this.state.operatorSuggestions}
              components={components}
              value={this.state.operator}
              onChange={this.handleChange("operator")}
              placeholder="Search name"
            />
            <div className={classes.divider} />
            <button onClick={e => this.props.removeSeleted(this.props.index)}>
              Remove
            </button>
          </NoSsr>
```

Comment: One advice, reformat and modulate your ReactJS code because it looks like Spaguetti code!

Comment: @R.García  thanks for your reply, can you give your suggestions so that in future I will fix it myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that you have is in the `div` parent from your **NoSsr component**. 
This div parent must be with the className: `queryBuilderContainer`. 
For instance, then you will not need put class to your `NoSsr`.

**See the code below:**

```
<div className={classes.queryBuilderContainer}>
      <NoSsr>
        <Select className={classes.queryBuilderContainerItem}...>
        <Select className={classes.queryBuilderContainerItem}...>
        ...
      </NoSsr>
 </div>
```

[image]

Comment: @Gracia thanks for your reply, can you tell me how you found out so that in future I will fix it myself :)

Comment: @Garcia can you help me this one too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53903369/using-react-redux-loading-bar-package-in-that-i-am-trying-to-show-loading-bar-co?noredirect=1#comment94655426_53903369