# using react redux loading bar package in that I am trying to show loading bar component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, material-ui

- I am new to redux.
- I am using reactredux loading bar package in that I am trying to use loading bar component.
- so I used flag for loading.
- till I get the response I am trying to show loadig bar.
- but I am not successful.
- so in the debugger I put a condole and prints true for loading but after that loading bar is not appearing.
- can you tell me how to fix it so taht in future I will fix it myself.
- providing my codesnippet and sandbox below.
- my code is in RecipeReviewCardList.js

https://codesandbox.io/s/5x02vjjlqp

```
 getPlayerssData() {
    this.setState({ loading: true });

    let comments = [];
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        comments = json;
        // comments = comments.slice(0,3);
        this.setState({
          loading: false,
          comments: comments
        });
        this.setState({ activeComments: comments.slice(0, 10) });
        //console.log(comments);
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { comments, loading } = this.state;
    // render your progress bar
    console.log("render loading--->", loading);
    if (loading) return <LoadingBar />;
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation for react-redux-loading-bar? You need to install its reducer to your store and dispatch its show/hide actions to trigger it.

Comment: @RyanC hey thanks for your reply...I went over the documentation again...now I updated the code in sandbox but still its not working...cna you help me... https://codesandbox.io/s/5x02vjjlqp

Comment: I still don’t see your code dispatching the show/hide actions.

Comment: @RyanC hey I updated code in index.js....I followed the documentaion https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-redux-loading-bar#usage its so confusing...can you update in my sandbox

Comment: Currently your code sandbox has a large amount of code in it unrelated to your question. Please simplify it to the simplest form that still demonstrates your problem.

Comment: I recommend a very simple page with just two buttons—one called “show” and one called “hide” where clicking “show” shows the loading bar and clicking “hide” hides it. No api calls and nothing else on the page other than the two buttons and the loading bar.

Comment: @Ryan sorry forgot to mention the file name in my question...its in - my code is in RecipeReviewCardList.js.. can you please help me since it will help me the api cproblem too

Comment: I will help if you do as I ask per the StackOverflow guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. You need to deal with one problem at a time. Right now your problem is that you don't understand how to use the loading bar, so you need to simplify your code to just deal with that.

Comment: @Ryan hey I tried with simple react app...but still not working...can you help me in stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zm9t65?file=components%2FApp.js

Comment: Right now it isn't even in a compiling state and you don't have any code (e.g. show/hide buttons per my suggestion) that is trying to control the display of the loading bar.

Comment: @RyanC but I thought I will load the component with page refresh....can you let me know whats the issue

Comment: Please fix the compile error in your stackblitz: `Error in /~/index.js (19:35)
App is not defined`